# Maximizing gVim on Windows 10 while also restoring all open files / tabs

Tags: buffers, gvim, microsoft-windows, window-management

On Windows 10, I installed gVim 8.1, so far I have made the following progress to make it *usable* for me:

1. I made changes directly to `_vimrc` file, in spite I know there is also a gVim specific configuration file, because I like it in one place.
2. I downloaded a color theme I really liked, and use it like so (for CLI version, the #3 below should be applied too):

   ```
   " load Atomified theme downloaded from:
   " http://vimcolors.com/797/atomified/dark
   " https://github.com/Siphalor/vim-atomified

   colorscheme atomified
   ```
3. In CLI version, I found there is a limited number of colors used, this can be remedied with:

   ```
   " switch CLI to full color support

   set termguicolors
   ```
4. I turned on line numbering with:

   ```
   " turn on line numbering

   set number
   ```
5. Regarding the GUI only, I have set:

   - to remove toolbar, as it is too small anyways on my HiDPI display, rendering it useless
   - to set proper font and its size for my HiDPI display
   - maximize gVim on startup

     ```
     " Do the following only if launching GUI VIM

     if has('gui_running')

       " remove toolbar, as it is too small anyways on my HiDPI display, rendering it useless
       set guioptions-=T

       " set proper font and its size for my HiDPI display
       set guifont=Consolas:h10

       " maximize gVim on startup
       " use ~x on an English Windows version, other languages see Alt + Spacebar for underlined character in your Close
       autocmd GUIEnter * simalt ~x

     endif
     ```

---

Thus far no problem, but once I added the following code to remember and restore open files on startup, it won't maximize fully, and it is also strangely resizing the main window down the startup:

```
" Go to last file(s) if invoked without arguments.
autocmd VimLeave * nested if (!isdirectory($HOME . "/.vim")) |
    \ call mkdir($HOME . "/.vim") |
    \ endif |
    \ execute "mksession! " . $HOME . "/.vim/Session.vim"

autocmd VimEnter * nested if argc() == 0 && filereadable($HOME . "/.vim/Session.vim") |
    \ execute "source " . $HOME . "/.vim/Session.vim"
```

**What did I make wrong and how to remedy it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found working, but completely different code on [Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_the_last_edited_file), from where I also used the strangely working code in the question.

As I don't fully understand it, I can't tell, if it's alright or not, but from today's testing it passed.

```
" Open last active file(s) if VIM is invoked without arguments

" This saves all open files / tabs on close
autocmd VimLeave * nested let buffernr = bufnr("$") |
    \ let buflist = [] |
    \ while buffernr > 0 |
    \ if buflisted(buffernr) |
    \     let buflist += [ bufname(buffernr) ] |
    \ endif |
    \   let buffernr -= 1 |
    \ endwhile |
    \ if (!isdirectory($HOME . "/.vim")) |
    \ call mkdir($HOME . "/.vim") |
    \ endif |
    \ call writefile(reverse(buflist), $HOME . "/.vim/buflist.txt")


" This restores all open files / tabs on startup
autocmd VimEnter * nested if argc() == 0 && filereadable($HOME . "/.vim/buflist.txt") |
    \ for line in readfile($HOME . "/.vim/buflist.txt") |
    \     if filereadable(line) |
    \   execute "tabedit " . line |
    \   set bufhidden=delete |
    \     endif |
    \ endfor |
    \ tabclose 1 |
    \ endif
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the [original solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16633/18061) has one or more flaws. I noticed that the saving procedure writes relative paths and / or **only file names**, which was a big problem, because when then loading the file list, of course it could not find the file(s).

This line is responsible for writing the file paths (names) into `buflist.txt`.

> ```
> \     let buflist += [ bufname(buffernr) ] |
> ```

I have re-written it, so that it writes full path to the file:

```
\     let buflist += [ fnamemodify(bufname(buffernr), ':p') ] |
```

And it so far, after an hour of testing, it works without error.

I will leave the original solution in place in order for you to be able to compare it, and if possible, revise it even better.

---

The whole, current, solution follows:

```
" Open last active file(s) if VIM is invoked without arguments

" This saves the tabs on close
autocmd VimLeave * nested let buffernr = bufnr("$") |
    \ let buflist = [] |
    \ while buffernr > 0 |
    \ if buflisted(buffernr) |
    \     let buflist += [ fnamemodify(bufname(buffernr), ':p') ] |
    \ endif |
    \   let buffernr -= 1 |
    \ endwhile |
    \ if (!isdirectory($HOME . "/.vim")) |
    \ call mkdir($HOME . "/.vim") |
    \ endif |
    \ call writefile(reverse(buflist), $HOME . "/.vim/buflist.txt")


" This restores the tabs on startup
autocmd VimEnter * nested if argc() == 0 && filereadable($HOME . "/.vim/buflist.txt") |
    \ for line in readfile($HOME . "/.vim/buflist.txt") |
    \     if filereadable(line) |
    \   execute "tabedit " . line |
    \   set bufhidden=delete |
    \     endif |
    \ endfor |
    \ tabclose 1 |
    \ endif
```